# LDAP extension not working in Php local server

Tags: php, dll, ldap

Config LDAP extension in my XAMPP server.

I tried these things:-

- Uncomment the LDAP extension in php.ini (;extension=php_ldap.dll)
- Added the  two DLL files  libeay32.dll, ssleay32.dll in system 32 and system folders

But still  LDAP extension was shown in my phpinfo() list in xampp server.

how to enable LDAP extension ...???

Comment: Silly question, but did you restart after commenting out the php.ini? Also, did you modify the php.ini through the xampp panel/browser/thingy? I know that WAMP (similar to xampp) doesn't use the really real php.ini, but rather generates one on the fly which can only be edited through the WAMP control panel.

Comment: And the second part of the question? :)

Comment: unable to load dynamic lib C:\xampp\php\ext\php_ldap.dll   The specified module could not found error appers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also copy libsasl.dll to System folders. References: http://wptidbits.com/webs/enable-php-ldap-module-in-xampp/

Comment: this is error now appers

ldap:Unable to onitialize module Module compiled with module API = 20090626

PHP compiled with module API =20131226

These options need to match

Comment: i think this is  version  problem i am using php 5.6 version